# SQL Server data separation for multiple clients

Tags: sql-server, database, data-structures

I'm developing an app which is supposed to be used by multiple clients. I need the data separation to be included in database level, so there will be no issues in data leak/invalid data display.

One approach I found is the dynamic table name creation for clients, which is not a good solution as the dynamic table names are causing issues in longer operations.

Is there any in-built or preferred methodology for this? adding a column called `clientid` and handling it via querying is not the solution I look for

Comment: can you share some examples and explain along with it

Comment: Need a bit more to go on like what the use case is and the driving force behind this. However even without that, I would suggest against building an exact copy of the table for each client. You'd still need to control which client sees which data, and whether the data is stored in different tables or different countries, at the end of the day, where the data lives isn't really the issue. Can you also expand on why having a clientid-like column isnt an option?

Comment: as a example, a client can register and use the functionality. Lets say a client can create a account and able to use the student management system. So the students under that client should not come under for another client. I need it to be handled in the db level, not to handle via a client id column and to filter in all the queries (if the query get missed, then the data is incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be the creation of sql-views with granted db-user permission for each client.

So when the client registers:

1. The application will create the specific db-user
2. Add a record in the clients table with the client-id
3. Create the specific view against the students table with the client-id filter embedded
4. Share the connection-string in the Client's client-application to utilize it and get only the filtered data